# How to change entitydatas for this project?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an underwater city. When I will be finished I would like to have citizens and guards in it. Is there a way I can either make an entire new entity or just edit a Villager's skin and get rid of trading. For the guards I thought I can change the skin. Or is there a way I can make them kill anything else within its radius except for myself and a few other players as well as the citizens?

Comment: I'm getting stuck on entity data

Comment: And I've tried to edit both skeleton and zombie data but I think this is a little over my head so I asked you guys for help.

Comment: You can get rid of villager trading with `entitydata`, but the other things you want will need resource packs (for changing their skin) and command blocks. Would an answer involving resource packs and command blocks be fine?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to make a villager attack another mob without rewriting code within the game files, which isn't gonna happen. The best you are able to do is to summon iron golems with `/summon VillagerGolem ~ ~ ~` (The capitals are necessary)

Comment: ok. clearly you don't understand the villager I'm just changing the skin, which is pretty easy, now what I'm trying to ask is how do I change a skeleton or a zombie's entity data so I can make them attack either enemy players or other mobs. BTW there are ways you can change what mobs can and can't do using score board or changing entity data which clearly you don't know.

Comment: Sorry to be too rash but thats the truth.

Comment: you cannot change the entity data to have them only attack the enemy players. If this IS what you're asking then YOU'RE the one who doesn't know what they're talking about, if it isn't, then you didn't ask clearly, because of the two people who have answered, both say the same.

Comment: omg there is a way to do it you idiot you can use java script or like a paste bin. but of course your not smart enough to know that or there is simply that score board. Geez guess I'll have to find peeps some where else who are smarter. For the record the stuff I'm trying to accomplish is probably way over you heads to begin with.